# Especializar apenas um metodo de classe template

Tags: c++, template

Eu possuo 2 tipos básicos de classes, **ClasseA** e **ClasseB**. A ClasseA tem um método que gera um inteiro, e a ClasseB tem um método que gera uma ClasseA.

Eu gostaria que no método de uma **ClasseC**, caso o template seja uma ClasseA(ou filhas) retornasse o inteiro pelo método diretamente, e caso o template seja uma ClasseB(ou filhas) gere uma ClasseA e depois retornasse o valor pelo  método, se fosse qualquer outra ele retornasse 0.

Resumi os códigos pra facilitar :

```
//ClasseA.h
class ClasseA{
public:
    int valor;
    ClasseA(int valor) : valor(valor){
    }
    int retValor() {
        int valor_final = valor;
        //alguns calculos
        return valor_final;
    }
}
//ClasseB.h
class ClasseB{
public:
    int valorA, valorB;
    ClasseB(int valorA, int valorB) : valorA(valorA) , valorB(valorB){
    }
    ClasseA toA() {
        int valor_finalA = valorA;
        int valor_finalB = valorB;
        //alguns calculos
        return ClasseA(valor_finalA / valor_finalB );
    }
}
//ClasseC.h
template<typename T> 
class ClasseC{
public:
    T classeT;
    ClasseC(T classeT) : classeT(classeT) {
    }
    //vários métodos
    int retValorFinal();
}
//ClasseC.cpp
template<typename T> 
int ClasseC<T>::retValorFinal(){
    //????
}
template class ClasseC<ClasseA>;
template class ClasseC<ClasseB>;
//outros tipos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução é fazer diferentes versões do método dependendo da classe do template.

```
template<>
int ClasseC<ClasseA>::retValorFinal() {
    std::cout << "Classe A\n";
    return classeT.retValor();
}

template<>
int ClasseC<ClasseB>::retValorFinal() {
    std::cout << "Classe B\n";
    return classeT.toA().retValor();
}

template<typename T>
int ClasseC<T>::retValorFinal() {
    std::cout << "Classe Desconhecida\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora funcionou perfeitamente